# Integral types messing up with sizeof(T)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-argument-deduction

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const void* data) : m_dataPtr(data) {}

template<typename T>
const T Get() {
    const T* readPoint = static_cast<const T*>(m_dataPtr);
    m_dataPtr = (const char *) m_dataPtr + sizeof(T);
    return *(readPoint);
}
private:   
    const void* m_dataPtr;
};
```

I got the above class, now I want to add a overload to the `operator>>` so that I can just do:

```
  Foo foo("Hello World");
  int8_t firstChar; // I want to get the first Char
  int16_t firstShort; // Get the 2 next bytes
  foo >> firstChar;
  foo >> firstShort;
```

So I created this overload function:

```
template<typename T>
void operator>>(Foo& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    rhs = lhs.Get<T>();
}
```

But I'm not sure if it works because of integral types getting transformed into `int` and then screwing up the `sizeof(T)`

Comment: Why would integral types be transformed into `int`?

Comment: Wouldn't all integral types be promoted to int?

Comment: *Expressions* of types narrower than `int` are promoted either to `int` or to `unsigned int` in many contexts. I can't think of a case where that would affect `sizeof (T)`, where `T` is a type name.

Comment: This code shouldn't compile.  You can't do pointer arithmetic on a `void*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Just fixed that

Comment: This code is going to give you serious alignment headaches.

Comment: @T.C. Why so? Please explain

Comment: @ReBirTH In brief, the value of `m_dataPtr` may not be properly aligned for `T`. For example, say that `m_dataPtr` was `0x8000`, then after you read a `char` it's `0x8001`, which is not properly aligned for you to then read a `int` (assuming `int`s are 4 bytes). Beyond that, your code  also have [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/2756719) problems. You are accessing the stored value of an object through a glvalue of an arbitrary type `T`. Unless T is one of the allowed types listed in the rule, you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick experiment shows that your code works as intended. I don't see any undesirable "promotions" happening anywhere. What exactly made you believe that something got promoted to `int` in your tests?

The only problem I see is

```
m_dataPtr += sizeof(T);
```

where `m_dataPtr` is declared as `const void *` pointer. Void pointers do not support pointer arithmetic. The proper way to express your intent would be

```
m_dataPtr = (const char *) m_dataPtr + sizeof(T);
```

In C++ language integral promotions happen only with a specific set of built-in operators. None of that seems to be a concern in your code. When you are using an overloaded `>>` operator in `foo >> firstChar`, integral promotions will not take place and template argument deduction will see the original types of all involved objects.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure how to make the pointer advance in the memory

Answer (score 1):

```
const T* readPoint = static_cast<const T*>(m_dataPtr);
```

the above line will generate alignment issues.

To solve this without the alignment issues, create a `T`, assert the `T` is POD (plain old data in C++03) or standard layout (in C++11).  Then do a `memcpy`.

```
template<typename T>
T Get() {
  // C++11:
  static_assert(
    std::is_standard_layout<T>::value,
    "Blitting non-standard layout bits doesn't work"
  );
  // C++03 static assert hack, makes array size 0 if fails:
  // bool pod_check[ std::is_pod<T>::value ];
  T result;
  memcpy( &result, m_dataPtr, sizeof(T) );
  m_dataPtr = (const char *) m_dataPtr + sizeof(T);
  return result;
}
```

RVO will eliminate the copy anyhow.

In addition, it is rarely a good idea to return `const T` for any type `T`.

Your code does not, however, have any issues with integer promotion.